# Customize the Django ContentTypes and AdminLog and Migration model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I am working on a Django project and it requires 3 different database servers with different engines like MySql, PostgreSQL and SQLite.

`SQLite` has all the client side setting table, tables with not shared data [app has a feature to not upload some data to the server] and configuration tables and it is on the client machine through a tweaked C# app to create a django server environment and show the django site in a browser control like a native application.

`PostgreSQL` has tables that can be accessed by different clients on the network and has different tables with values of shared data. They maintain integrity with `SQLite` data through `ContentType`.

Django provides the `contentType` table that is created in both SQLite and PostgreSQL. Due to heavy use of `other database managing tables` we require them to be in a MySQL database on a separate server. So it would be great to have `django_content_types`, `django_admin_log` and `django_migration` in that `MySQL` server.

`ContentTypes` table is also used a lot and it is difficult to maintain `contentTypes` form two different database tables so we require it to be in one separate one with values form both the databases. And when one goes there why not the other two: `django_migration`, `django_admin_log`.

Also there is requirement to store raw SQL DDL queries in the database to track changes outside of the Django ORM and so it makes sense to add rows to `django_migration` and a new column to store raw SQL queries.

Also, this is the last thing for sure, `django_admin_log` only logs admin-site changes and also lacks data in message columns when new row is added or deleted. We really require it to store the JSON of values added to the particular table when adding and when deleting, the instance [json format of row] to message column about the record deleted. And require it to log all transactions on instances of both the databases.

I am looking to [customize/extend/create my own and override] these models in a Django App to gain the above expected behavior and have a portable app to use it in future such projects.

Regards,
    Aagam Sheth